# How to compress image using Sharp JS after uploading with Multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer, sharp

I feel like my code is complete frankenstein at this point but I do wonder why this formula does not work.

Once the file is uploaded, I can access the path with req.file.path and so I try to plug that into sharp but nothing happens. I'm not getting any errors or the expected result. (I'm using .rotate() to make it more obvious in testing)

```
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function(req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, 'public/uploads')
        },
        filename: function(req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
        }
    });
    
    var upload = multer({
        storage: storage
    });
    
    router.post("/new", upload.single('image'), function(req, res) {

    sharp(req.file.path).rotate();
    
        var post = {
            title: req.body.title,
            image: uploadedImage,
            description: req.body.description,
            body: req.body.body
        }
    
        Blog.create(post, function(err, newPost) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect("/")
            } else {
                res.redirect("/");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You either need to use `async/await` or Promises as the calls to `sharp` are asynchronous. You will also need to do something with the modified/rotated file like copying it to a `Buffer` or saving to a `File`. See [these examples](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-resize#examples) in the documentation.

```
// use an async function
router.post("/new", upload.single('image'), async function(req, res) {
  await sharp(req.file.path).rotate().toFile('/path/to/file');
  // ... rest of your code
});
```